# Stack Bar Plot For R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How can I make a stack barchart for my Shiny Dashboard?
For example I want one bar for 2016 with number of applications, number of accepted applications and the number enrolled, but all of these values together in one column - stacked.

[this is my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3lE6.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ggplot2` package to create stacked barplot with `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`. However to convert [wide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data) `data.frame` format into [narrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data) one required by `ggplot2` it is neccessary to use `melt` function of `reshape2` package.

Please see the code below for barchart in Shiny Dashboard environement:

```
# load the required packages
library(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "
Enrolment Applications Accepted Students Enrolled 
                 3 2017 30 25 5 20 
                 2 2016 24 21 3 20 
                 1 2015 22 20 2 17") 


#Dashboard header carrying the title of the dashboard
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard")  

#Sidebar content of the dashboard
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
)


frow2 <- fluidRow(

  box(
    title = "Enrollement"
    ,status = "primary"
    ,solidHeader = TRUE 
    ,collapsible = TRUE 
    ,plotOutput("enrollement", height = "300px")
  )

)



# combine the two fluid rows to make the body
body <- dashboardBody(frow2)

#completing the ui part with dashboardPage
ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'This is my Page title', header, sidebar, body, skin='red')

# create the server functions for the dashboard  
server <- function(input, output) { 
  #creating the plotOutput content

  output$enrollement <- renderPlot({
    df$Enrolment <- factor(df$Enrolment)
    df$Not_Accepted <- df$Applications - df$Accepted
    df$Not_Enrolled <- df$Accepted - df$Enrolled
    df2 <- melt(df[, c("Enrolment", "Enrolled", "Not_Enrolled", "Not_Accepted")])

    ggplot(df2, aes(Enrolment, y = value, fill = variable)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Output:

[image: shiny dashboard]